# Fade opacity at the top of page when scrolling down javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to reverse this code:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $('#portfolio-entrybox li').each(function (i) {
        var oTop = $(this).offset().top;
        var oHeight = $(this).outerHeight();

        var wTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var wHeight = $(window).height();

        if (oTop < wTop + wHeight) {
            var diff = ((wTop + wHeight - oTop) / oHeight);

            if (diff > 1) diff = 1;
            else if (diff < 0) diff = 0;

            $(this).css('opacity', diff);
        }
    });
});
```

I need the items to fade at the top instead of fading on the bottom. They should start with opacity 100% and as you scroll down the it changes to 0%. Same principal as this code instead just reversed.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RrBEV/) with live demo.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I did it:

Change your `if-statement` to this:

```
if (oTop < wTop) {
    var diff = ((wTop - oTop) / oHeight);

    if (diff >= 1) diff = 1;
    else if (diff <= 0) diff = 0;

    diff = 1 - diff;

    $(this).css('opacity', diff);
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RrBEV/69/).

Answer (score 0):

The above solution doesn't seem to work right according to what my browser seems to be doing (check out https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUqHp.png).

However, I also made an attempt at this which you can view here: http://jsfiddle.net/RrBEV/70/

```js
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $('#portfolio-entrybox li').each(function (i) {
        var oTop = $(this).offset().top;
        var oHeight = $(this).outerHeight();

        var wTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var wHeight = $(window).height();

        if (oTop + oHeight > wTop) {
            var diff = ((oTop + oHeight - wTop) / oHeight);

            if (diff > 1) diff = 1;
            else if (diff < 0) diff = 0;

            $(this).css('opacity', diff);
        }
    });
});
```